# Is there a way to convert double like this one - 1.2676506002282294E+30 to regular "non-exponential" notation

Tags: c#, double

How to convert `Math.Pow(2,1000)` from

> 1.0715086071862673E+301

### to

> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376

That's because I need to find the sum of all digits of this number. Thank You!

Comment: You can't convert; you've already lost precision. Use `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thank You! It worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BigInteger from System.Numerics. It has its own Pow method.

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger bigInteger = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow(2, 1000);

string powString = bigInteger.ToString();

int sum = 0;

foreach (char letter in powString)
{
    int letterValue = int.Parse(letter.ToString());
    sum += letterValue;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

I get 1366.